# Problema para salir del do while en java

Tags: java, while

me estoy volviendo por dar la cabeza contra la pared.
El programa trata sobre leer nombres y notas, imprimir la cantidad de alumnos con nota mayor a 8 y la
cantidad de alumnos con nota = 7.
El programa debe de finalizar al ingresar el nombre "zidane zinedine".

El problema esta en que al poner el booleano en false el programa sigue en un bucle infinito y no
logro encontrar el error..
Muchas gracias de antemano!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Tres{
   public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    String nombre = " ";
    int nota = 0;
    boolean i = true;
    int cantAprobados = 0;
    int cantSiete = 0;
    do {  
        System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del alumno");
        nombre = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese nota del alumno");
        nota = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        if  (nombre == "zidane zinedine"){
            i = false;
        }
        if (nota >= 8){
            cantAprobados = cantAprobados + 1;
        } else if (nota == 7){
            cantSiete = cantSiete + 1;
        }
    } while (i == true);
    
    System.out.println("La cantidad de alumnos aprobados es: "+ cantAprobados);
    System.out.println("La cantidad de alumnos con nota 7 es: "+ cantSiete);

  }   
  }
```

Comment: Para empezar, no puedes comparar cadenas de este modo: `if  (nombre == "zidane zinedine"){`, eso nunca será verdadero, tienes que usar `equals()` para comparar cadenas: `if  ( nombre.equals("zidane zinedine") ){` corrige esa comparación y revisa de nuevo el código y dinos si sigues teniendo problemas.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por corregirme! me ayudaste mucho

Comment: @A.Cedano _podría_ ser verdadero. `String nombre = "zidane"; if (nombre == "zidane") System.out.println("Es lo mismo");`. En ese caso es lo mismo.... _pero_ es un detalle de la mecánica de los Strings. En general se deben comparar con el método `equals()` como dice @A.Cedano.

Comment: @SuicidePanda la comparación de cadenas en Java se debe de realizar con  equals()  y no con == . agregue una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas realizando una comparación de cadenas con `==` lo cual es incorrecto, debes usar el método [**equals()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) de esta forma al ser igual la cadena que introduces con la cadena "zidane zinedine" el valor de i sera `false`, lo cual provocará la terminación del bucle:

```
 //if  (nombre == "zidane zinedine"){
  if  (nombre.equals("zidane zinedine")){
       i = false;
  }
```

realizalo de esta forma:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Tres{
   public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    String nombre = " ";
    int nota = 0;
    boolean i = true;
    int cantAprobados = 0;
    int cantSiete = 0;
    do {  
        System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del alumno");
        nombre = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese nota del alumno");
        nota = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        //if  (nombre == "zidane zinedine"){
        if  (nombre.equals("zidane zinedine")){
            i = false;
        }
        if (nota >= 8){
            cantAprobados = cantAprobados + 1;
        } else if (nota == 7){
            cantSiete = cantSiete + 1;
        }
    } while (i == true);
    
    System.out.println("La cantidad de alumnos aprobados es: "+ cantAprobados);
    System.out.println("La cantidad de alumnos con nota 7 es: "+ cantSiete);

  }   
}
```

**En Java se útiliza la función equals() para comparar strings, nunca debería usarse el operador ==** .

Answer (score 2):

La solución de Jesus se ve bien (solo le falta el equals() para comparar) pero quiero aportar otra forma de salir del bucle, aunque ya hayan aceptado su respuesta:

```
do {  
    System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del alumno");
    nombre = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese nota del alumno");
    nota = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    if (nombre.equals("zidane zinedine")) {
        break;
    }
    if (nota >= 8) {
        cantAprobados++;
    } else if (nota == 7) {
        cantSiete++;
    }
} while (true);
```

Eso nos permite ahorrarnos el `else` y todo un nivel de anidación.

Answer (score -2):

Prueba con este codigo:

```
do {  
      System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del alumno");
      nombre = in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Ingrese nota del alumno");
      nota = in.nextInt();
      in.nextLine();
      if  (nombre == "zidane zinedine")
      {
         i = false;
      }
      else
      {
         if (nota >= 8)
         {
            cantAprobados = cantAprobados + 1;
         } 
         else if (nota == 7)
         {
            cantSiete = cantSiete + 1;
         }
      } 
} while (i == true);
```

Quedo al pendiente de tus comentarios.

Comment: Se puede colocar `while (i);`.

Comment: Esto nunca terminaría el bucle @SuicidePanda

Comment: Editaría mi respuesta para completarla con la suya pero... hasta donde recuerdo no había problema igualarlo así, Ademas no seria nada ético. Pero si no es la correcta igual puede quitar la palomita y colocar la que considere la respuesta correcta.

Comment: No te preocupes @JesusDanielVazquezLorenzo , puedes corregirla, lo importante es dar a los usuarios de la comunidad infomación correcta y de calidad, te sugiero también agregar explicación del código para que sea mejor tu respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Aquí `nombre == "zidane zinedine"` comparas referencias y son distintas, por ende, el resultado de la condición es `false`. Esto funcionaría en lenguajes como por ejemplo, C++ ó C#, ya que la clase `String` sobrecarga el operador relacional (`==`) pero en Java no.

Comment: Intenta dar una explicación de tu código, las respuesta de solo código son consideradas de mala calidad.